# Cannot use .container-fluid in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

guys. I am new to bootstrap so forgive me if this isn't the greatest question in the world. I am working on a portfolio project and would like to use the container-fluid class to make my site responsive. I have downloaded the bootstrap pallette plugin for netbeans along with installing it. I then used the link to access bootstrap. Whenever I use the container fluid class, my content does not fit the browser correctly and is not responsive. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Sias</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="newcss.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="main-banner">
            <img src="images/Yup.gif" alt=""/>
            </div>

            <main class="wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/Team.png" alt=""/></li>                
                <li><img src="images/Target.png" alt=""/></li>                
            </ul>            
            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/computer.png" alt=""/></li>                
                <li><img src="images/Bulb.png" alt=""/></li>                
            </ul>
            </main>
        </div>
```

Comment: you still need rows and columns in Bootstrap, inside container-fluid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think you misunderstood how bootstrap elements work. Here are some quick tips.

1. `.container` and `.container-fluid` are both responsive. It is all about the way they respond to the width of the viewport. While **.container** fits the browser while having a fixed width for different screen sizes, **.container-fluid** changes its width according to screen size. But they are all **responsive.**
2. Unless there is an overlapping css, `Bootstrap Css` should be working without any problems. Which means that, the content does actually fit the browser. But the main question here is : `Which elements are needed to fit the browser`. In your case, this is **vague**. Is there a problem with your `images`, or your `banner-container`?
3. The markup depends on what you would like to achive as layout. And probabbly you should know, that **Bootstrap** is based on `12 column layout.`Do you want two images in one row? Then use two columns in one row. Like so :

   ```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <img src="Team.png" alt="team"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <img src="Target.png" alt="target"/>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   Would you like your images fit the window? Then use `.col-sm-12` class inside your image tag.

`<img src="Target.png" class="col-sm-12" alt="team"/>`

As you see, you can even read it in the class names. Do you want to pull a div to the right. Then use:

`<div class="pull-right">`

> All of the answers that are given before me are correct. Just try them and play with your code, and see how they fulfill your needs. But if you ask me, Read [Bottstrap Css Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) first.

**By the way, if you need your custom css overwrite the Bootstrap's then call it after.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of the layout you want, but this is one example using Bootstrap columns:

```
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="main-banner">
            <img src="Yup.gif" alt="yup"/>
            </div>

        <main class="wrapper">
        <ul>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <li><img src="Team.png" alt="team"/></li>
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <li><img src="Target.png" alt="target"/></li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <li><img src="computer.png" alt="computer"/></li>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
            <li><img src="Bulb.png" alt="bulb"/></li>
              </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
        </main>
    </div>

</body>
```

Also, place new.css *after* Bootstrap. Otherwise, Bootstrap will override new.css - probably not what you want.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Blazemonger I only just now learned that I had permission to comment!